# Sending a flash notice in Rails doesn't pop up on redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a redirect in an `ApplicationController`-method and want to send a notice through:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def redirect_if_no_user
    if current_user.nil?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: t('errors.session_expired')
    end
  end

end
```

I'm calling `redirect_if_no_user` in some other controller actions.

Unfortunately I cannot see a notice until I do another reload on the homepage manually (After I already got redirected to it via the method).
Is this behaviour intended? Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Do you know about `flash.now`?

Comment: @RichPeck please go on!

Comment: Sure, let me write it out

Answer (score 2):

From rails documentation, ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash )

By default, adding values to the flash will make them available to the next request, but sometimes you may want to access those values in the same request. For example, if the create action fails to save a resource and you render the new template directly, that's not going to result in a new request, but you may still want to display a message using the flash. To do this, you can use flash.now in the same way you use the normal flash:

```
flash.now[:notice] = t('errors.session_expired')
redirect_to root_path
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you *might* benefit from [`flash.now`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now).

I've had issues like that which you mentioned (no flash on redirect), and I haven't solved it entirely yet. One thing I did find was using `flash.now` to help someone else solve their issue:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def redirect_if_no_user
    if !user_signed_in? #-> assuming you're using devise
      flash.now[:notice] = t('errors.session_expired')
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

This may not work. If it doesn't, I'll delete.

Comment: so I'm trying this and it doesn't show any message at all. Do I need to explicitly print it out this time?

Comment: When you say "no message at all", which message did you get last time?

Comment: The message of `notice:` in my OP. But I don't need to print it out, it will appear automagically. (But after a second reload)

Comment: Ah okay. With your other message, is it based on javascript at all??

Comment: Interesting. Can you try changing `redirect_to root_path` to `render root_path` to see what happens?

Comment: I need the redirect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102620/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-supersize).

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before...

The flash notice you're seeing (eventually) is likely NOT the one you think it is.  You have

redirect_to root_path

But I would wager that your root_path has it's own redirect, and that redirect means you've lost the flash notice.  When you then submit on root_path you're doing another call on redirect_if_no_user and this time you see the flash message.

You can usually work around this (a redirect following a redirect losing flash message)

with the `flash.keep` method.

```
def my_root_path_action
  flash.keep
  ...
end
```

... or it might be needed in one of your `before_action` or `before_filter` methods if they're redirecting before your action is called.

Comment: that's an interesting theory but I don't call the method on the homepage controller. As I mentioned before I'm calling the method in some controller actions, the home controller is not the one which is included. So when I'm doing the reload, I'm actually not triggering this notice again.

Comment: Ok, does the homepage controller have any `before_action` or `before_filter` that may do some redirects?

Answer (score 0):

```
    flash[:notice] = t('errors.session_expired')
    redirect_to root_path
```

Try that.